# jquery determine which class triggered event

Tags: jquery

I have 3 different groups of divs that all handle different menu selections.  Let's suppose that one is wrapped in class="class1", another is wrapped in class="class2", etc.

These classes would also be exclusive of each other.

Then suppose I have code:

```
$('.class1, .class2, .class3').click(function(e){
    //which class was it that triggered this event?
});
```

Is it possible to find this out? I suppose I can use hasClass() for each instance, or this.className - but in the latter case there may be many classes.  Assuming again that class1 and class2 etc never mix, is there some native call that would do this?  FYI the string inside $( ) might eventually be a variable.  Thanks

Comment: DOM elements trigger not a class. What you are referring is a selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.class1, .class2, .class3').click(function(e){
     alert("Was pressed: "+$(this).attr('class'));
});
```

Use $(this) to get the invoked element, you can use different methods like hasClass(), addClass(), attr(), etc.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer thought ot be clear on my OP, the thing I was hoping for was some native method that said "of the classes that were there *IN THE STRING*, this is the one that triggered it" - as there could be an unlimited number of classes present in the element.  I guess what I need to do is compare as follows in my answer below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var className = $(e.target).attr('class');
```

The variable `className` should have the class name.

Answer (score 0):

it appears that there is no *specific* answer to this, so here is the thing that I'll write that will address my need:

```
var menuGroup={
    '.group1':{ /*relevant data*/ },
    '.group2':{ /*relevant data*/ }
}
var triggers='';
for(var i in menuGroup)triggers+='.'+i+', ';
triggers=triggers.replace(/, $/,'');
$(triggers).click(function(e){
    var classes=this.className.split(/\s+/);
    for(var i in classes){
        for(var j in menuGroup){
            if(classes[i]==menuGroup[j].replace(/\./,'')){
                var triggerClass=classes[i];
                break(2);
            }
        }
    }
    //we now have triggerClass..
});
```